# Writing a script for ash?

Tags: linux, shell-script

My VPN is behaving funny sometimes, and I have to restart it often. I wanted to write a script which does that for me. It doesn't have to be anything fancy, just a shortcut for the commands I have to type into the terminal. More specifically: it will look at the running processes. If it finds a running vpnc process, it will kill it. Then it will start vpnc.

I've written bash scripts of similar complexity, but now I don't have a bash, only an ash. Until now, the only difference I noticed is that there are much less commands available, but then, I don't use it very often. So I have some questions.

1. Is writing ash scripts different
   than writing bash scripts?
2. Is there something specific to 
   consider when doing it?
3. When the script is ready, how can I 
   deploy it? For bash, I just put
   the executable file under /usr/lib
   and run it by typing the file name
   into the command line, will this
   work with ash?
4. Are there any special pitfalls to 
   watch out for in the script I want
   to write? I think that the killing
   process part may get hairy, if I
   write something that kills the wrong
   process, but even then running the
   script shouldn't break anything 
   permanently, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there's anything bash specific in this, most of the "magic" is in the external commands.  So, something like:

```
#!/bin/ash  
pgrep vpnc >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    /etc/init.d/vpnc stop
    sleep 1
    pkill vpnc
    sleep 1
    pkill -9 vpnc
    sleep 1
    /etc/init.d/vpnc start
fi
```

Will work assuming that you have pgrep and pkill installed and that your init script is called `vpnc` and lives in `/etc/init.d` (and that `ash` lives in `/bin`).  Drop it anywhere in `$PATH`, set the execute bit (`chmod +x myscript`) and you simply have to call it by the name you saved it as.

Traditionally locally installed binaries (and scripts) would live in `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/lib`.  If that doesn't exist and isn't in your current `$PATH` just create the directory (`mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`) and edit the file that sets `$PATH` (probably something under `/etc`).

Note that with a little effort you could wrap this in a script that does something like:

```
#!/bin/ash
pgrep vpnc
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ping -n -q -c 4 ip.at.other.side
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        /usr/local/bin/myscript
    fi
fi
```

Call that from cron every *N* minutes and, when the VPN is running and the ping to the IP at the other side fails, it'll restart the VPN.

*Caution - I've simply thrown these together from experience, no testing has been done and I've never used ash.  Some tweaking or rework may be required.*

---

Ok, if you don't have cron you could wrap the second script like:

```
#!/bin/ash
while [ true ]; do
    pgrep vpnc
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        ping -n -q -c 4 ip.at.other.side
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            /usr/local/bin/myscript
        fi
    fi
sleep 60
done
```

To have it run in the background use `nohup`:

```
nohup /usr/local/bin/mywrapper &
```

You should find that there's at least one server that responds to ping, possibly even the VPN endpoint.  If that doesn't work try the DNS servers or routers (people particularly rarely lock down routers).

Comment: About the first suffestion: Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of time for trial-and-error; I didn't even know about the pgrep and pkill commands. 
Now, I am curious about your script. What is the /etc/init.d/vpnc stop line supposed to do? When I try it, vpnc tries to run, looking for a configuration file named stop, and exits with an error message. And second, what is pkill -9 vpnc supposed to do? I looked on the man and didn't find an option to execute pkill with a numeric parameter.

Comment: About the second suggestion: interesting idea. Only I don't have cron. There is a daemon called alarmd which provides an API for time scheduling, but I don't think that I can use it from the shell. I found a forum with the suggestion to use an endless loop which sleeps for N minutes and then calls my script, does this solution, maybe I'll try this. Only then I'll have to leave the terminal open all the time. And as I need the VPN for Internet access when I'm in the uni campus WiFi, I don't have any IP to test for, anyway not one where I can tell the admin to expect regular pings from me.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the actual script I used:

```
#! /bin/ash
pgrep vpnc >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 pkill vpnc
 sleep 1
fi
vpnc /etc/vpnc/hybrid.conf
```

where hybrid.conf is the configuration file for the vpnc client. I'd like to learn more about scripting, so if somebody notices an example of bad practice here, please tell me about it.

Comment: There's no need to use `$?` you can do `if command` (including redirection, if needed) directly (without square brackets).